# Extracting data from text file in AMPL without adding indexes

Tags: matrix, indexing, ampl

I'm new to AMPL and I have data in a text file in matrix form from which I need to use certain values. However, I don't know how to use the matrices directly without having to manually add column and row indexes to them. Is there a way around this?

So the data I need to use looks something like this, with hundreds of rows and columns (and several more matrices like this), and I would like to use it as a parameter with index i for rows and j for columns.

`t=1`

`0.0  40.95   40.36   38.14   44.87   29.7    26.85   28.61   29.73   39.15   41.49   32.37   33.13   59.63   38.72   42.34   40.59   33.77   44.69   38.14   33.45   47.27   38.93   56.43   44.74   35.38   58.27   31.57   55.76   35.83   51.01   59.29   39.11   30.91   58.24   52.83   42.65   32.25   41.13   41.88   46.94   30.72   46.69   55.5    45.15   42.28   47.86   54.6    42.25   48.57   32.83   37.52   58.18   46.27   43.98   33.43   39.41   34.0    57.23   32.98   33.4    47.8    40.36   53.84   51.66   47.76   30.95   50.34 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this. The closest thing is probably the table format given in [section 9.3 of the AMPL Book](https://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/12-data.pdf). This avoids needing to give indices for every term individually, but it still requires explicitly stating row and column indices.

AMPL doesn't seem to do a lot with position-based input formats, probably because it defaults to treating index sets as unordered so the concept of "first row" etc. isn't meaningful.

If you *really* wanted to do it within AMPL, you could probably put together a work-around along these lines:

- declare a single-index param with length equal to the total size of your matrix (e.g. if your matrix is 10 x 100, this param has length 1000)
- edit the beginning and end of your "matrix" data file to turn it into appropriate format for a single-index parameter indexed from 1 to n
- then define your matrix something like this:

  param m{i in 1..nrows,j in 1..ncols} := x[j+i*(ncols-1)];

(not tested, I won't promise that I have rows and columns the right way around there!)

But you're probably better off editing the input file into one of the standard AMPL matrix formats. AMPL isn't really designed for data wrangling - you can do it in a pinch but if you're doing this kind of thing repeatedly it may be less trouble to code it in a general-purpose language e.g. Python.